# applicationDidFinishLaunching and applicationShouldTerminate

Tags: cocoa, nsapplication

I have a Cocoa App (fairly complicated with OpenGL calls and external IO and serial line ...).
A while back I made some modifications and now my `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is not called anymore! So far I couldn't find out way (I have my project under source control but I can't find the culprit yet!).

But the stranger thing is the `applicationShouldTerminate` and `applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed`.

My question is why `applicationShouldTerminate` is being called while `applicationDidFinishLaunching` which is in the same `.m` file in same `@implementation` is not called.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

Comment: Are you sure the method is written exactly as it is in the docs? Should be `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`

Comment: Is anything written to the console? Maybe an exception is being thrown before `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` gets called, and that causes it not to be called?

Comment: Yes it is exactly as it is in the docs, to make sure I copied and pasted it both in `.h` and `.m` file. and I write a lot of stuff to the console but if there was an exception it would have stopped right? Is there any kind of exception that I could have handled be causing this?!

Comment: that was a typo while writing the question, this is the actual code `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification`